# UITabBarItems in UITabBar show after I click the item not when application launches

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

This application I'm writing has a problem.

I'm setting up the `UITabBar` in my application window and set the icons in the view files.
But when i run the app, the first icons show up (because the view is loaded I guess) and the other icons do not show up until I click them.

Do i need to implement `self.tabBarItem` in some other method not `viewDidLoad`?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    SubscriptionsController *subscriptionsController = [[SubscriptionsController alloc] init];
    FavoritesController  *favoritesController  = [[FavoritesController  alloc] init];
    CategoriesController *categoriesController  = [[CategoriesController alloc] init];
    TagsController   *tagsController    = [[TagsController   alloc] init];
    HelpScreenController *helpScreenController  = [[HelpScreenController alloc] init];

    tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        subscriptionsController, 
        favoritesController, 
        categoriesController, 
        tagsController, 
        helpScreenController, 
        nil
        ];

    [window addSubview:tabBar.view];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

//The View

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tabIcon = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Abonime" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"subscr.png"] tag:0];
    self.tabBarItem = tabIcon;
    [tabIcon release];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should set the tabBarItem property in a view controller's designated initializer (judging from your code, it must be `-init` for each of the controllers). In fact, the tab bar controller is smart enough to load the views on demand, that is, the tabBarItem property should be set before `viewDidLoad` gets sent.

Also, you seem to be leaking all the view controllers. To fix that, do the following:

```
SubscriptionsController *subscriptionsController = [[[SubscriptionsController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: How do I do this in swift 2?

Comment: I've been looking at this answer but still need some more specifics. Can you please give a complete answer in Swift 4? Thanks :)

Comment: @AndyLebowitz The issue has actually nothing to do with the language you use. You should make sure you assign `tabBarItem`s to your view controllers **before** you configure your `UITabBarController` with those view controllers, because in order to display the tab bar items `UITabBarController` needs to access the `tabBarItem` property of its child view controllers. When the child view controllers receive `viewDidLoad`, the tab bar items should have already been displayed, so it's too late to set `tabBarItem` in `viewDidLoad`. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Correct. The icons don't show up because the view (other than the first one, isn't loaded yet). And doesn't get loaded until you tap a view because viewDidLoad isn't called until then.

Remove the code in the individual UIViewControllers viewDidLoad and Do this...

```
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SubscriptionsController", @"class", [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tax.png"], @"icon", @"Abonime", @"title", nil],
                                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FavoritesController", @"class", [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tax.png"], @"icon", @"Abonime", @"title", nil],
                                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"CategoriesController", @"class", [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tax.png"], @"icon", @"Abonime", @"title", nil],
                                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TagsController", @"class", [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tax.png"], @"icon", @"Abonime", @"title", nil],
                                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"HelpScreenController", @"class", [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tax.png"], @"icon", @"Abonime", @"title", nil],
                                                nil];

NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [NSMutableArray array] ;

 for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [controllers count]; i++)
 {
    id newClass = [[NSClassFromString([[controllers objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"class"]) alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
    tabItem.image = [[controllers objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"icon"];
    tabItem.title = [[controllers objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    tabItem.tag = i;
    [(UIViewController*)newClass setTabBarItem:tabItem];
    [tabItem release];
    [controllerArray addObject:newClass];
    [newClass release];
 }

 tabBar.viewControllers = controllerArray;
```