# UITabbar items not showing until click following upgrade to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBar` that was functioning well prior to my upgrade to Xcode 7 and now I can't figure out what's going on for the life of me. I've tried several solutions including setting the `imageWithRenderingMode` for each tab I create, trying to change the background color of the `UITabBar` to see if maybe the items were just white, and updating the icons themselves to new versions. My default selected tab shows up just fine, and then when I select another tab, the text shows up, but no image. ( The text persists and changes to the default gray when moving to another tab as well. )

I've attached a screenshot of what I'm seeing, and here's how I'm currently implementing the tabbar.

Function to create tabbar:

```
void MakeTabBar(id target)
{
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.recentView = [[RecentView alloc] init];
    appDelegate.groupsView = [[GroupsView alloc] init];
    appDelegate.settingsView = [[SettingsView alloc] init];
    appDelegate.homeView = [[HomeView alloc] init];

    NavigationController *navController1 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.recentView];
    NavigationController *navController2 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.groupsView];
    NavigationController *navController4 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.settingsView];
    NavigationController *navController5 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.homeView];

    appDelegate.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = DEFAULT_TAB;
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:COLOR_OUTGOING];

    NSMutableDictionary *customAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    BOOL isAdmin = [currentUser[@"isAdmin"] boolValue];
    if(isAdmin){
        [customAttributes setObject:currentUser[@"isAdmin"] forKey:@"isAdmin"];
        appDelegate.peopleView = [[PeopleView alloc] init];
        NavigationController *navController3 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.peopleView];
        appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController5, navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4];
    } else{
        appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController5, navController1, navController2, navController4];
    }

    BOOL isTester = [currentUser[@"isTestData"] boolValue];
    if(isTester){
        [customAttributes setObject:currentUser[@"isTestData"] forKey:@"isTestData"];
    }

    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.tabBarController];
}
```

Code in each view to create tab:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    {
        [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_consultants"]];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Consultants";
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After tons of trial and error I found the issue was due to navigation controllers and my tabbar was included in my UINavigation that was colored differently to support the top nav bar. I separated them and now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem solved it with setting the title of shown view controllers in their init function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417666/3647974.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue. 
I solved it by writing following code

```
let storyboard   = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let vc1          = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
vc1.tabBarItem   = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleIrregularityBasicContentView(), title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "home"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "home_1"))
```

Hope it will help you